# Trying to increment a variable but stop at the max value

Tags: php, html, if-statement, increment

This code works, but I'm sure it's very bad. Is there a better more cleaner way to achieve this?

```
 <?php
 $banner_count = count(glob("./img/banners/" . "*"));
 if (!$_GET) {
     $random = rand(1,$banner_count - 1);
 } else {
     $random = $_GET['id'];
         }
 ?>

 <?php include("nav_header.html"); ?>
 <div class="inln">
 <a href="./img/banners/<?php echo $random; ?>.png" style="all:unset;"><img class="zero" src="./img/banners/<?php echo $random; ?>.   png" title="Random banner image"></a>

<a href="?id=<?php $p=$random; if ($p - 1 <= 1) { echo 1; } else { echo $p - 1; } ?>">&lt</a>
 <a href="?id=<?php $n=$random; if ($n + 1 >= $banner_count) { echo $banner_count - 1; } else { echo $n + 1; } ?>">&gt</a>
 </div>
```

The last 2 statement generate forward and back links and I'm trying to make it stop incrementing and de-incrementing when the min/max of $banner_count is reached.

Comment: Why not just disable the links when you're at the end?

Comment: I don't know how, that's why I'm asking, I'm completely new to this

Comment: Try `href="?id=<?=max( 1, $random - 1 )?>"` and `href="?id=<?=min( $banner_count - 1, $random + 1 )?>"`

Comment: Thanks :) min() max() function is exactly what I needed